# How to remove duplicates and count total records in array by id

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

The exercise is as follows: Object in which the keys are the names of the banks and the values ​​the number of clients that only have accounts in that bank.

whit this array:

```
const accounts = [ 
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 }, 
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 },
   { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 },
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 },
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 },
   { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 },
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 },
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 }
];
```

I have this for now:

```
function banksFidelity() {
  var map = accounts.reduce(function(map, account) {
    var bankByid = account.bankId;
    var clientByid = account.clientId;

    map[bankByid] = map[clientByid] || 0 + clientByid

    return map

  }, {})

  return map

}
```

**Current result is:**

```
{1: 6, 2: 5, 3: 5}
```

**Desired result is:**

```
{1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4}
```

Comment: Can you give us the starting object?

Comment: What you have is an object and not an array

Comment: @ivan, yes! array edit!

Comment: Adding the client ID to the total makes no sense at all. Client IDs aren't amounts that are meant to be added.

Comment: Also, arithmetic has higher precedence than logical operators, so it should be `(map[clientByid] || 0) + clientByid`

Comment: Can you explain your desired results? I think it should be `{ 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1}`. The only unique client for bank 1 is 6, there's no unique client for bank 2, and the only unique client for bank 3 is 4.

Comment: The duplicate link *does not* help this problem. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Your desired result doesn't match your description of the problem. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the array of accounts object with the [`.foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and fill another object as you go by checking if the client already has an account with this bank. You're left with an object (`clients`) associating each client with an array of the banks he uses:

```
{
  "1": [3, 2],
  "2": [2, 3, 1],
  "3": [1, 3, 2],
  "4": [3],
  "5": [3, 2, 1],
  "6": [1]
}
```

Use another [`.foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) loop to fill another object (`exclusiveClients`) that will associate banks with the number of clients that only use this bank to get the desired result:

```
{
  "1": 1,
  "3": 1
}
```

Here's the code:

```js
const accounts=[{clientId:6,bankId:1,balance:15000},{clientId:1,bankId:3,balance:18000},{clientId:5,bankId:3,balance:135000},{clientId:2,bankId:2,balance:5600},{clientId:3,bankId:1,balance:23000},{clientId:5,bankId:2,balance:15000},{clientId:3,bankId:3,balance:45900},{clientId:2,bankId:3,balance:19000},{clientId:4,bankId:3,balance:51000},{clientId:5,bankId:1,balance:89000},{clientId:1,bankId:2,balance:1600},{clientId:5,bankId:3,balance:37500},{clientId:6,bankId:1,balance:19200},{clientId:2,bankId:3,balance:10000},{clientId:3,bankId:2,balance:5400},{clientId:3,bankId:1,balance:9000},{clientId:4,bankId:3,balance:13500},{clientId:2,bankId:1,balance:38200},{clientId:5,bankId:2,balance:17000},{clientId:1,bankId:3,balance:1000},{clientId:5,bankId:2,balance:600},{clientId:6,bankId:1,balance:16200},{clientId:2,bankId:2,balance:10000}]

let clients = {};

accounts.forEach(({bankId, clientId}) => {

  if(clients[clientId] && !clients[clientId].includes(bankId)) {
  
    clients[clientId].push(bankId);
  
  } else if(!clients[clientId]) {
  
    clients[clientId] = [bankId];
  
  }
  
});


let exclusiveClients = {};

Object.entries(clients).forEach(([client, banks]) => {

  if(banks.length == 1) {
  
    const bank = banks[0];
    exclusiveClients[bank] = (exclusiveClients[bank] + 1) || 1;
    
    
  }
  
});

console.log(exclusiveClients)
```

Comment: Your result is different from his desired result, can you explain that? Is his expectation wrong?

Comment: The question says to count "clients that only have accounts in that bank". Where does your code avoid counting clients that have accounts in a different bank?

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array to remove all the duplicates, then reduce that array to form your final object.

```js
const accounts = [ 
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 }, 
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 },
   { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 },
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 },
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 },
   { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 },
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 },
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 }
]

let result = accounts
  // Remove duplicates
  .reduce((arr, itm) => {
    let containsClient = !!arr.find(i => i.clientId == itm.clientId && i.bankId == itm.bankId)
    return !containsClient ? arr.concat(itm) : arr
  }, [])
  // Get the counts after duplicates are removed
  .reduce((obj, itm) => {
    if (obj[itm.bankId]) obj[itm.bankId]++
    else obj[itm.bankId] = 1
    return obj
  }, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

variation: using references so when we update a client once, we can retrieve the information from wherever he has been added/reference copied

```js
 const accounts = [ 
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 }, 
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 },
   { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 },
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 },
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 },
   { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 },
   { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 },
   { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 },
   { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 },
   { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 },
   { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 }
  ]

var clients = {}
var dupes = {}
var banks = {}
accounts.forEach(a=>{
    if(dupes[a.clientId+'_'+a.bankId]){
        return;
    }
    banks[a.bankId] = banks[a.bankId] || new Set;
    if(clients[a.clientId]){
        //this client has already a bank
        //different than the current one
        clients[a.clientId].multi = true;
    }else{
        clients[a.clientId]={}
    }
    banks[a.bankId].add(a.clientId)
    dupes[a.clientId+'_'+a.bankId] = 1;
}, {})
var res = Object.keys(banks).reduce((acc,bId)=>{
    acc[bId] = [...banks[bId]].filter(x=>!x.multi).length
    return acc;
},{})
console.log('res ', res)
```